# Carto, Named Maps, writing a list to check with 'in' sql format

Tags: carto, sql, api

I'm trying to use a Named Map in Carto with the 'in' operator to avoid to make various calls to paint the same way a few features.

I want to do this:

`SELECT * FROM madrid where id_tramo in ('2805200000011','2805200000041','2805200000051','2805200000061')`

In my case, I'm using a string with simple quotes and commas to separate values.This is part of the call:

> config: "provincia":"a_coruna","municipio":"15041","idtramos":"'1504100012461','1504100014191','1504100012951'","layer0":1}

You can see the parameter "idtramos" being "'1504100012461','1504100014191','1504100012951'". Of course, the Named Map is getting in trouble with simple quotes and commas because I'm using sql_literal as variable type. As we can see in [Carto](https://carto.com/docs/carto-engine/maps-api/named-maps#placeholder-types). And this is what I'm getting:

> errors:["syntax error at or near "1504100012461""]

It's possible to do it with a Named Map? If not I will have to make a loop calling the each feature, but I understand is not the best way to do it. Maybe there is another way to do it.

This is the Named Map:

`'paint_bloqued_tramos' : """{
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "name": "paint_bloqued_tramos",
    "auth": {    ...    },
    "placeholders": {
        "provincia": {
            "type": "sql_literal",
            "default": "No hay variable provincia y no puede filtrar en la query del NM"
        },
        "municipio": {
            "type": "sql_literal",
            "default": "No hay variable municipio y por el NM da error"
        },
        "idtramos": {
            "type": "sql_literal",
            "default": "No hay variable idtramo y no puede filtrar en la query del NM"
        }
    },
    "layergroup": {
        "layers": [{
            "type": "cartodb",
            "options": {
                "cartocss_version": "2.1.1",
                "cartocss": "#layer { line-width: 7; line-color: #000000; line-opacity: 0.3; line-comp-op: color-burn; }",
                "sql": "SELECT * FROM <%= provincia %>_tram where municipio_id = '<%= municipio %>' AND id_tramo in (<%= idtramos %>)"
            }
        }]
    }
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`'sql_ident'`](https://carto.com/docs/carto-engine/maps-api/named-maps#placeholder-types) so quotes are treated correctly. So your template would have a definition like this (approx):

`{
  "auth": {
    "method": "open"
  },
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "name": "named_map_test_in",
  "placeholders": {
    "filter": {
      "type": "sql_ident",
      "default": "'Spain'"
    }
...
     {
        "type": "cartodb",
        "options": {
          "sql": "select * from populated_places where adm0name in (<%= filter %>)",
          "layer_name": "populated_places",
          "cartocss": "#populated_places{ marker-line-opacity: 0;  marker-width: 3;  marker-fill: <%= color %>; marker-allow-overlap: true;}",
          "cartocss_version": "2.1.1",
          "interactivity": [
            "cartodb_id",
            "name"
          ],
.....`

and an example of map instantiation you can try here http://jsfiddle.net/adndz2zr/1/ just change the list of countries and see how they are filtered.

Comment: The different parameter types are shown here: https://carto.com/docs/carto-engine/maps-api/named-maps